# REACT - how can wait until api call finish to load a path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I use the axios post to request to the back-end if the user have access to the application. The problem is the axios returns undefined and then true or false . Have a private Route to manage what to do in case returns true or false (in this case undefined = false) ,is axios the problem or is there some other way? like wait until returns true or false

### IsLogin.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
const axios = require('axios');
export const AuthContext = React.createContext({})

export default function Islogin({ children }) {
   const isAuthenticated =()=>{
       try{
            axios.post('/api/auth').then(response => {
               var res = response.data.result;
               console.log(res)
               return res
           })
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
           return false
       }

   }
  
   var auth = isAuthenticated()
   console.log(auth);
   return (
       <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth}}>
           {children}
       </AuthContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

### privateRoute.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import  {AuthContext}  from '../utils/IsLogin';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

   const {isAuthenticated}  = useContext(AuthContext)
   
   return (

       // Show the component only when the user is logged in
       // Otherwise, redirect the user to /unauth page
       <Route {...rest} render={props => (
           isAuthenticated ?
               <Component {...props} />
           : <Redirect to="/unauth" />
       )} />
   );
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

### app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Islogin>
      <Header/>
    <Banner/>
     <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/index" component={Landing} />
     <PrivateRoute path="/upload" component={Upload} exact />
     <PublicRoute restricted={false} path="/unauth" component={Unauthorized} exact  />
    </Switch>
    </Islogin>
    </BrowserRouter>
  
    </>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to return anything in your post request. You should be updating your context store

```js
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    try {
        axios.post('/api/auth').then(response => {
            var res = response.data.result;
            console.log(res)
            // update your context here instead of returning
            return res
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return false
    }
}
```

In your private route, have a `componentDidUpdate` style `useEffect` hook to check for changes in authentication status and update an internal flag on an as-needed basis

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [validCredentials, setValidCredentials] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof isAuthenticated === 'boolean') {
            setValidCredentials(isAuthenticated)
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated])


    return (

        // Show the component only when the user is logged in
        // Otherwise, redirect the user to /unauth page
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            validCredentials ?
                <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to="/unauth" />
        )} />
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for help, what did you mean when you said update the context? y need to delete this code?
  
`return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{res}}>
                {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )`

Comment: I never said you should delete that code. You need it to hold `isAuthenticated`. you need to `dispatch` an update to change `isAuthenticated` to `true`/`false` based on your api response

Comment: @Andrew I have a similar problem, I am using Redux for global auth state. I have the exact same `PrivateRoute`. My problem is: when user is logged in and they click refresh, then the `Login` component is rendered because the auth state is `false`. I am also making an api call to my backend, when that call returns if the user is authorized then `Dashboard` protected route is rendered. So there is a brief time period in which `Login` is rendered and 0.5 seconds later, `Dashbaord` is rendered. How do I avoid showing the `Login` before getting result from my API ?

Comment: @HarshitTrehan I personally would not have an entire page for logging in and instead have a home page that has login functionality on the UI. If that's not possible, then hiding the process behind a loader is the easiest way.

Comment: @Andrew by Loader do you mean a separate generic component that is reusable on other pages as well ? Or is it some kind of built in React functionality that I'm unaware of ?

Comment: @HarshitTrehan There are libraries. It's also easy to make yourself. Or you can use React's proposal. https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Answer (score -1):

I am curious as to why you didn't use 'async await',lol.

You are making a post request to the endpoint '/api/auth',but you didn't give it any data to post,like:

```
try{
       axios.post('/api/auth',{username,password}).then(response => {
           var res = response.data.result;
           console.log(res)
           return res
       })
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
           return false
       }
```

Comment: The authentication it's manage by the back-end the endpoint /api/auth only returns true or false